# Generate two webpack packages with slightly different configs at once

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to generate twice the amount of packages/chunks in webpack that the only difference is one loads `includePaths` of IE9 styles and the other doesn't, and then I lazy load one package or the other depending on the browser. I've got the lazy loading part down but I'm not sure how to generate all the bundles. Here's the standard config with the relevant parts being the `scss` loader and the `appPaths` variable set at the top:

```
var fs      = require('fs'),
    path    = require('path'),
    webpack = require('webpack'),
    apps = fs.readdirSync('./app');
    appModuleRegex = new RegExp("^(" + apps.join('|') + ")/(.*)$"),
    appPaths = apps.map(function(appName) {
        return 'app/' + appName + '/src';
    });

entrypoints = {};

apps.forEach(function(appName) {
    entrypoints[appName] = [ 'webpack/hot/dev-server', appName + '/app' ]
});

entrypoints['vendor'] = [
    'classnames',
    'd3',
    'fetch',
    'lodash',
    'moment',
    'react',
    'react-router',
    'react-select',
    'zxcvbn2',
];

module.exports = {
    entry: entrypoints,
    output: {
        path: '/web/dist',
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /\.test.js$|node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!autoprefixer-loader?{browsers:["last 2 versions","ie >= 9"]}'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: 'style!css!autoprefixer-loader?{browsers:["last 2 versions","ie >= 9"]}!sass?includePaths[]=' + appPaths.join(',')
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                exclude: /\.file\.svg$/i,
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.file\.svg$|\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
                loaders: [
                    'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
                    'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        root: path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules")
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
        alias: {
            'fetch': '/web/node_modules/whatwg-fetch/fetch'
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("vendor", "vendor.bundle.js"),
        new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(appModuleRegex, function(result) {
            result.request = result.request.replace(appModuleRegex, "/web/app/$1/src/$2");
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: '/web/dist/',
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        watchOptions: {
            aggregateTimeout: 500,
            poll: 500
        },
        stats: {colors: true}
    }
}
```

And the only change I want to make is here at the top:

```
appPaths = apps.map(function(appName) {
    // change to ie9-styles
    return 'app/' + appName + '/src/ie9-styles';
});
```

Which you can see changes the scss loader to look in a different directory to load the IE9 styles correctly.  How can I generate all these packages at once instead of one or the other?